# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,15) (10,) (5,15)

Tags: python, numpy

I just want a clear explanation of the what I am doing wrong. I have just created a model and I am testing with a different data set. I have just tested my model using my X_test (that was transformed using the StandardScaler) and everything is fine. I am now trying to validate the model using another data set. Since I am using a **StandardScaler** I am trying to transform the 5 rows of the new data I have just acquired using the **sc.transform(new_data)** to finally use model to predict. However, when I am trying to do so I have that operand **ValueError**:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,15) (10,) (5,15)
```

Here is what I' am doing:

```
new_data=new_data[:5]
new_data=sc.transform(new_data)
```

Could someone explain to me without too much jargon what it is going on?I have gone through the other links but I cannot seem to get understand it.

Comment: What is the shape of `new_data`?

Comment: The new data shape is (5,15)/ well done--- . I was sleeping on that my new algorithm is only taking 10 column. So sorry for posting thanks